# Proper way to have foreign keys to subclasses in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

A nurse orders medical supplies via a requisition to one of three different supplies, all supplied by a supplier.

Nurse > Requisition < Supplies (3 kinds) < Supplier

Since items can be one of three kinds and a requisition may not exist yet for an item, the requisition table has the foreign keys of the 3 supply types.

The issue: my correctly listed foreign keys all point to 3 different tables, all but one of which will not have a corresponding foreign key for each entry.

I get the following error:

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
>   ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MMM1339.ITEMNO_PHAR_FK) violated - parent key not found

```
CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER
(SUPPLIERNO   INT,
 SUPPLIERNAME VARCHAR2(100),
 PHONENO VARCHAR2(12),
 ADDRESS VARCHAR(100),
 FAXNO VARCHAR(12),
 CONSTRAINT SUPPLIERNO_SSPL_PK PRIMARY KEY(SUPPLIERNO));

CREATE TABLE SUPPLIES_PHARMACEUTICAL
(ITEMNO         INT,
SUPPLIERNO      INT,
NAME            VARCHAR2(25),
DESCRIPTION     VARCHAR2(25),
QUANTITYINSTOCK INT,
REORDERLEVEL    INT,
COSTPERUNIT     DECIMAL(6,2),
DOSAGE          VARCHAR2(12),
CONSTRAINT ITEMNO_PHAR_PK PRIMARY KEY(ITEMNO));

CREATE TABLE SUPPLIES_SURGICAL
(ITEMNO         INT,
NAME            VARCHAR2(25),
DESCRIPTION     VARCHAR2(25),
QUANTITYINSTOCK INT,
REORDERLEVEL    INT,
COSTPERUNIT     DECIMAL(6,2),
SUPPLIERNO      INT,
CONSTRAINT ITEMNO_SUP_PK PRIMARY KEY(ITEMNO));

CREATE TABLE SUPPLIES_NONSURGICAL
(ITEMNO         INT,
NAME            VARCHAR2(25),
DESCRIPTION     VARCHAR2(25),  
QUANTITYINSTOCK INT,
REORDERLEVEL    INT,
COSTPERUNIT     DECIMAL(6,2),
SUPPLIERNO      INT,
CONSTRAINT ITEMNO_NONSURG_PK PRIMARY KEY(ITEMNO));

CREATE TABLE STAFF_CHARGENURSE
(STAFFNO   INT,
 ADDRESS   VARCHAR2(25),
 POSITION  VARCHAR2(12),
 BUDGET    DECIMAL(6,2),
 SPECIALTY VARCHAR2(12),
 CONSTRAINT STAFFNO_CHNURSE_PK PRIMARY KEY(STAFFNO));

 CREATE TABLE REQUISITION
 (REQNO INT,
  STAFFNO INT,
  STAFFNAME VARCHAR2(25),
  WARDNO INT,
  ITEMNO INT,
  QUANTITY INT,
  DATEORDERED DATE,
  DATERECIEVED DATE,
  CONSTRAINT REQ_PK PRIMARY KEY(REQNO));
```

Foreign keys:

```
 ALTER TABLE SUPPLIES_PHARMACEUTICAL
     ADD CONSTRAINT SUPPLIERNO_PHA_FK FOREIGN KEY(SUPPLIERNO) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(SUPPLIERNO)
     DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
 ALTER TABLE SUPPLIES_SURGICAL
     ADD CONSTRAINT SUPPLIERNO_SURG_FK FOREIGN KEY(SUPPLIERNO) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(SUPPLIERNO)
     DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
 ALTER TABLE SUPPLIES_NONSURGICAL
     ADD CONSTRAINT SUPPLIERNO_NONSURG_FK FOREIGN KEY(SUPPLIERNO) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(SUPPLIERNO)
     DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
 ALTER TABLE REQUISITION
     ADD CONSTRAINT STAFFNO_REQ_FK FOREIGN KEY(STAFFNO) REFERENCES STAFF_CHARGENURSE(STAFFNO)
     DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
 ALTER TABLE REQUISITION
     ADD CONSTRAINT ITEMNO_PHAR_FK FOREIGN KEY(ITEMNO) REFERENCES SUPPLIES_PHARMACEUTICAL(ITEMNO)
     DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
 ALTER TABLE REQUISITION
     ADD CONSTRAINT ITEMNO_SURG_FK FOREIGN KEY(ITEMNO) REFERENCES SUPPLIES_SURGICAL(ITEMNO)
     DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
 ALTER TABLE REQUISITION
     ADD CONSTRAINT ITEMNO_NONSURG_FK FOREIGN KEY(ITEMNO) REFERENCES SUPPLIES_NONSURGICAL(ITEMNO)
     DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Test data:

```
 INSERT INTO REQUISITION VALUES(1, 20, 'Julie Wood', 8, 888520, 2, '27-FEB-2018', '15-MAR-2018');
 INSERT INTO REQUISITION VALUES(2, 20, 'Julie Wood', 8, 923956, 1, '25-FEB-2018', '28-FEB-2018');
 INSERT INTO REQUISITION VALUES(3, 21, 'Sarah Michaels', 7, 054802, 3, '20-FEB-2018', '22-FEB-2018');

 INSERT INTO SUPPLIES_PHARMACEUTICAL VALUES (823456, 100001, 'Zanax', 'Anti Depressant', 8, 2, 100.50, '50mg');
 INSERT INTO SUPPLIES_PHARMACEUTICAL VALUES (923956, 100001, 'Zupridol', 'Blood Pressure Treatment', 12, 5, 50, '20mg');
 INSERT INTO SUPPLIES_PHARMACEUTICAL VALUES (3952, 200001, 'Amibreezax', 'Artificial Ear Wax', 2, 1, 200, '5g');
 INSERT INTO SUPPLIES_PHARMACEUTICAL VALUES (4955, 200001, 'Ambridax', 'Skin Treatment', 5, 10, 20, '2mg');

 INSERT INTO SUPPLIES_SURGICAL VALUES (54802, 'Scalpel', 'Surgical Tool', 20, 10, 200.42, 100001);
 INSERT INTO SUPPLIES_SURGICAL VALUES (634520, 'Stitches', 'Suture Tool', 100, 10, 2.50, 200001);

 INSERT INTO SUPPLIES_NONSURGICAL VALUES (888520, 'Cart', '5ftx2ftx3ft', 2, 0, 200.00, 100001);
 INSERT INTO SUPPLIES_NONSURGICAL VALUES (423, 'Tool Holder', 'Holds Inspection Equip.', 4, 2, 50.00, 100001);

 INSERT INTO STAFF_CHARGENURSE VALUES(20, '32 Stark St. Portland, OR', 'Charge Nurse', 8000.99, 'Head Trauma');
 INSERT INTO STAFF_CHARGENURSE VALUES(21, '18 Wilson Rd Portland, OR', 'Charge Nurse', 6000, 'Epidermus');

 INSERT INTO SUPPLIER VALUES (100001,'Company A', '503-222-3333', '100 SE Stark Rd Portland, OR', '503-666-4444');
 INSERT INTO SUPPLIER VALUES (200001,'Company B', '666-333-4444', '500 SE Bilerica Rd Akron, OH', '666-444-3333');

 COMMIT;
```

Comment: If this is the script you tried to run the only problem is the order of your insert is wrong, first you the suplies_whatever, then supplier, then staff and lastly your requisition which is the table that link then all. To have a link the linked itens must exist first.

Comment: Reordered but there is still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in responses to your other related questions, there is no superclass and no subclasses. `SUPPLIES_PHARMACEUTICAL`, `SUPPLIES_SURGICAL` and `SUPPLIES_NONSURGICAL` are just tables with no connection to each other.

All enabled constraints are enforced. Defining them as deferrable just puts off validation until the next `commit`, which doesn't really change anything in your example. If you define three constraints on a column, there is no syntax or mechanism to say *'only one of these constraints needs to be enforced'*, and I can't see how such a system would ever be workable.

In data modelling, you define subtypes using either

1. A single table (e.g. `SUPPLIES`) with a `category` or similar indicator column, or
2. A parent table having just the common columns, and child tables under it having just the type-specific columns, linked back to the parent via foreign key constraints. The child table can have a unique or primary key on the FK column, making it an optional 1:1 relationship.

Other tables can then have FK constraints referencing either the parent or one of its children, as required.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your modified original code (UPPER case original, lower case: modifications),  using @William Robertson's [ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422232/sql-error-parent-key-not-found-for-improperly-used-foreign-keys): {1} using a single SUPPLIES table, {2} with a is_surgical column, and {3} a pharma_dosage table.  Maybe you like it ...

```
CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER
(SUPPLIERNO   integer,
 SUPPLIERNAME VARCHAR2(100),
 PHONENO VARCHAR2(12),
 ADDRESS VARCHAR(100),
 FAXNO VARCHAR(12),
 CONSTRAINT SUPPLIERNO_SSPL_PK PRIMARY KEY(SUPPLIERNO));

-- one table instead of 3
create table supplies (
  ITEMNO          integer,
  SUPPLIERNO      integer,
  NAME            VARCHAR2(25),
  DESCRIPTION     VARCHAR2(25),
  QUANTITYINSTOCK integer,
  REORDERLEVEL    integer,
  COSTPERUNIT     number(6,2),
  is_surgical     varchar2(1) not null, 
  constraint supplies_surgical_yn_chk check( is_surgical in ('Y','N') )
, constraint supplies_pk primary key( itemno )
, constraint supplies_fk foreign key( supplierno )
  references supplier( supplierno )
);

create table pharma_dosage ( 
  itemno          integer
, dosage          varchar2( 64 ) not null 
, constraint pharma_supplies_fk foreign key( itemno )
  references supplies( itemno )
, constraint pharma_supplies_pk primary key( itemno )
);
```

Two more tables, and - commented out - things we don't need:

```
-- not needed
-- CREATE TABLE SUPPLIES_PHARMACEUTICAL
-- CREATE TABLE SUPPLIES_SURGICAL
-- CREATE TABLE SUPPLIES_NONSURGICAL
CREATE TABLE STAFF_CHARGENURSE
(STAFFNO   integer,          
 ADDRESS   VARCHAR2(25),
 POSITION  VARCHAR2(12),
 BUDGET    DECIMAL(6,2),
 SPECIALTY VARCHAR2(12),
 CONSTRAINT STAFFNO_CHNURSE_PK PRIMARY KEY(STAFFNO));

 CREATE TABLE REQUISITION
 (REQNO integer,             
  STAFFNO integer,           
  STAFFNAME VARCHAR2(25),
  WARDNO integer,            
  ITEMNO integer,            
  QUANTITY integer,         
  DATEORDERED DATE,
  DATERECIEVED DATE,
  CONSTRAINT REQ_PK PRIMARY KEY(REQNO),
  constraint req_fk foreign key ( itemno ) references supplies ( itemno )
);
-- not needed
-- ALTER TABLE SUPPLIES_PHARMACEUTICAL ADD CONSTRAINT SUPPLIERNO_PHA_FK 
-- ALTER TABLE SUPPLIES_SURGICAL ADD CONSTRAINT SUPPLIERNO_SURG_FK
-- ALTER TABLE SUPPLIES_NONSURGICAL ADD CONSTRAINT SUPPLIERNO_NONSURG_FK 
ALTER TABLE REQUISITION ADD CONSTRAINT STAFFNO_REQ_FK 
FOREIGN KEY(STAFFNO) REFERENCES STAFF_CHARGENURSE(STAFFNO) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
-- not needed
-- ALTER TABLE REQUISITION ADD CONSTRAINT ITEMNO_PHAR_FK 
-- ALTER TABLE REQUISITION ADD CONSTRAINT ITEMNO_SURG_FK 
-- ALTER TABLE REQUISITION ADD CONSTRAINT ITEMNO_NONSURG_FK
```

**INSERTs**

```
-- parents first
begin
  INSERT INTO STAFF_CHARGENURSE VALUES(20, '32 Stark St. Portland, OR', 'Charge Nurse', 8000.99, 'Head Trauma');
  INSERT INTO STAFF_CHARGENURSE VALUES(21, '18 Wilson Rd Portland, OR', 'Charge Nurse', 6000, 'Epidermus');

  INSERT INTO SUPPLIER VALUES (100001,'Company A', '503-222-3333', '100 SE Stark Rd Portland, OR', '503-666-4444');
  INSERT INTO SUPPLIER VALUES (200001,'Company B', '666-333-4444', '500 SE Bilerica Rd Akron, OH', '666-444-3333');
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**More test data**

```
begin
-- pharmaceutical
INSERT INTO SUPPLIES( itemno, supplierno, name, description, quantityinstock
, reorderlevel, costperunit, is_surgical )
VALUES (823456, 100001, 'Zanax', 'Anti Depressant', 8, 2, 100.50, 'N');
INSERT INTO SUPPLIES( itemno, supplierno, name, description, quantityinstock
, reorderlevel, costperunit, is_surgical )
VALUES (923956, 100001, 'Zupridol', 'Blood Pressure Treatment', 12, 5, 50, 'N');
INSERT INTO SUPPLIES( itemno, supplierno, name, description, quantityinstock
, reorderlevel, costperunit, is_surgical )
VALUES (3952, 200001, 'Amibreezax', 'Artificial Ear Wax', 2, 1, 200, 'N');
INSERT INTO SUPPLIES( itemno, supplierno, name, description, quantityinstock
, reorderlevel, costperunit, is_surgical )
VALUES (4955, 200001, 'Ambridax', 'Skin Treatment', 5, 10, 20, 'N');
-- pharma_dosage
insert into pharma_dosage ( itemno, dosage ) values ( 823456, '50mg' ) ;
insert into pharma_dosage ( itemno, dosage ) values ( 923956, '20mg' ) ;
insert into pharma_dosage ( itemno, dosage ) values ( 3952, '5g' ) ;
insert into pharma_dosage ( itemno, dosage ) values ( 4955, '2mg' ) ;
-- surgical
INSERT INTO SUPPLIES( itemno, supplierno, name, description, quantityinstock
, reorderlevel, costperunit, is_surgical )
VALUES (54802, 100001, 'Scalpel', 'Surgical Tool', 20, 10, 200.42, 'Y');
INSERT INTO SUPPLIES( itemno, supplierno, name, description, quantityinstock
, reorderlevel, costperunit, is_surgical ) 
VALUES (634520, 200001, 'Stitches', 'Suture Tool', 100, 10, 2.50, 'Y');
-- nonsurgical
INSERT INTO SUPPLIES( itemno, supplierno, name, description, quantityinstock
, reorderlevel, costperunit, is_surgical)
VALUES (888520, 100001, 'Cart', '5ftx2ftx3ft', 2, 0, 200.00,  'N');
INSERT INTO SUPPLIES( itemno, supplierno, name, description, quantityinstock
, reorderlevel, costperunit, is_surgical )
VALUES (423, 100001,'Tool Holder', 'Holds Inspection Equip.', 4, 2, 50.00,  'N');
-- requisition
INSERT INTO REQUISITION VALUES(1, 20, 'Julie Wood', 8, 888520, 2, '27-FEB-2018', '15-MAR-2018');
INSERT INTO REQUISITION VALUES(2, 20, 'Julie Wood', 8, 923956, 1, '25-FEB-2018', '28-FEB-2018');
INSERT INTO REQUISITION VALUES(3, 21, 'Sarah Michaels', 7, 054802, 3, '20-FEB-2018', '22-FEB-2018');
end ;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Now, some SELECTs ...**

```
SQL> select * from supplier ;
SUPPLIERNO  SUPPLIERNAME  PHONENO       ADDRESS                       FAXNO         
100001      Company A     503-222-3333  100 SE Stark Rd Portland, OR  503-666-4444  
200001      Company B     666-333-4444  500 SE Bilerica Rd Akron, OH  666-444-3333  

SQL> select * from supplies ;
ITEMNO  SUPPLIERNO  NAME         DESCRIPTION               QUANTITYINSTOCK  REORDERLEVEL  COSTPERUNIT  IS_SURGICAL  
823456  100001      Zanax        Anti Depressant           8                2             100.5        N            
923956  100001      Zupridol     Blood Pressure Treatment  12               5             50           N            
3952    200001      Amibreezax   Artificial Ear Wax        2                1             200          N            
4955    200001      Ambridax     Skin Treatment            5                10            20           N            
54802   100001      Scalpel      Surgical Tool             20               10            200.42       Y            
634520  200001      Stitches     Suture Tool               100              10            2.5          Y            
888520  100001      Cart         5ftx2ftx3ft               2                0             200          N            
423     100001      Tool Holder  Holds Inspection Equip.   4                2             50           N             

SQL> select * from requisition;
REQNO  STAFFNO  STAFFNAME       WARDNO  ITEMNO  QUANTITY  DATEORDERED  DATERECIEVED  
1      20       Julie Wood      8       888520  2         27-FEB-18    15-MAR-18     
2      20       Julie Wood      8       923956  1         25-FEB-18    28-FEB-18     
3      21       Sarah Michaels  7       54802   3         20-FEB-18    22-FEB-18     

SQL> select * from staff_chargenurse;
STAFFNO  ADDRESS                    POSITION      BUDGET   SPECIALTY    
20       32 Stark St. Portland, OR  Charge Nurse  8000.99  Head Trauma  
21       18 Wilson Rd Portland, OR  Charge Nurse  6000     Epidermus    

SQL> select * from pharma_dosage;
ITEMNO  DOSAGE  
823456  50mg    
923956  20mg    
3952    5g      
4955    2mg
```

**Version 2**

If you still want to have one "supertype" and 3 "subtype" tables, have a look at the following DDL.  You can probably find a solution that's kind of "in between" the two.  (What follows is just "proof of concept" code, several columns and some of the original tables omitted.)

```
create table supplies (
  supplierno number primary key
, category varchar2( 16 ) 
, constraint unique_parentcategory unique ( supplierno, category )
, constraint check_category check (
    category in ( 'surgical', 'non-surgical', 'pharmaceutical' )
  )
);
```

Then ...

```
create table supplies_pharmaceutical (
  supplierno number primary key
, category varchar2( 16 )
-- 
-- more "specific" columns here 
--
, constraint check_category1 check ( category in ( 'pharmaceutical' ) )
, constraint s_p_fk foreign key ( supplierno, category ) 
  references supplies ( supplierno, category )
) ; 

create table supplies_nonsurgical (
  supplierno number primary key
, category varchar2( 16 )
-- 
-- more "specific" columns here 
--
, constraint check_category2 check ( category in ( 'non-surgical' )  )
, constraint s_n_fk foreign key ( supplierno, category ) 
  references supplies ( supplierno, category )
) ; 

create table supplies_surgical (
  supplierno number primary key
, category varchar2( 16 )
-- 
-- more "specific" columns here 
--
, constraint check_category3 check ( category in ( 'surgical' )  )
, constraint s_s_fk foreign key ( supplierno, category ) 
  references supplies ( supplierno, category ) 
) ;
```

Test data:

```
begin
  insert into supplies( supplierno, category ) values ( 1000, 'pharmaceutical' ) ;
  insert into supplies( supplierno, category ) values ( 2000, 'non-surgical' ) ;
  insert into supplies( supplierno, category ) values ( 3000, 'surgical' ) ;

  insert into supplies_pharmaceutical( supplierno, category ) 
    values ( 1000, 'pharmaceutical' ) ;
  insert into supplies_nonsurgical( supplierno, category ) 
    values ( 2000, 'non-surgical' ) ;
  insert into supplies_surgical( supplierno, category ) 
    values ( 3000, 'surgical' ) ;
end;
/

-- must fail:
insert into supplies ( supplierno, category ) values ( 1001, 'food' ) ;

insert into supplies_pharmaceutical( supplierno, category ) 
  values ( 2000, 'pharmaceutical' ) ;
```